# azure web app dos not run

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

Having problem with a web app I am running from azure.
I have a web app AND a database in azure service from microsoft. 
I can check from sql studio that the database is ok , with no error. I got the connection string and put it in the webconfig of the app . but once I run the app i get this error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Login failed for user 'null'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed
>   for user 'null'.

If I run the app in my local PC but using the connection string  from azure it runs fine , no error( al so meaning the connection string seems fine

Comment: In case that you know why is this the way azure works with a null user you can provide some explanation thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer. it says user is null because in azure the web app is by default with connection string with user ID = null . It does not matter that the app was deployed with a correct connection string. It will not work .
I had to go to azure >web app service> application settings> connection strings and add the correct string. Now works fine .
Keep the default with user null in case is needed by the system(i dont know that)
This post helped me
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141239/login-failed-for-user-on-sql-azure-from-azure-hosted-web-application